# Recriar os elementos HTML de uma Div para outra Div pela ClassName

Tags: javascript, css, dom, for, replicação

Bom, alguns vão me sugerir utilizar o `cloneNode(true)` do Javascript para fazer um `appendChild(var)` no [DOM](https://tableless.com.br/tenha-o-dom/).

Mas para este caso, ja utilizei deste recurso nativo, mas não atendeu a minha necessidade. Por que, quando faço um clone fiel de seu filho no DOM, o CSS que deveria estilizar todo seus elementos perde-se, não define em nada.

Então acredito, que recuperando seus atributos com o laço `for` seja o ideal para replicar novamente os elementos. Veja o que tenho tentado:

```js
var str = document.getElementById('nome').value;

if (document.getElementsByClassName(str)) {

        document.getElementById('B').innerHTML = '';
        
var figura = document.body.getElementsByTagName('img');

var evento = document.body.getElementsByTagName('a');

        for (var i in figura, evento) {

            var image = figura[i];
            var titulo = image.className;
            var endereco =  image.src;

            var clic = evento[i];
            var link = clic.href;

            if ((titulo == str) || (clic == this.link)) {
                var xerox = image.innerHTML;
                 var copia = endereco.innerHTML;

                 var clique = link.innerHTML;
             document.getElementById('B').innerHTML = '<p><a href="'+ clique +'"><img src="'+ copia +'" class="'+ xerox +'"></a></p>';
             }   
         }
}
```

```css
#A {
    float : right;
    width : 115px;
    height : 400px;
    overflow: auto;
    padding  : 10px;
    border : thin solid silver;
}

#B { 
    overflow-x: auto;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    width : 400px;
    height : 100px;
    padding  : 10px;
    border : thin solid silver;
} 

#B p {
    padding : 10px;
    margin : 0 auto;
    cursor : pointer;
    display : inline-blinkk;
    display : inline;
    vertical-align : top;
}
```

```html
<div id="A">
  <p><a href="http://www.monkie.com.br" onclick="return false"><img src="https://lorempixel.com/100/100/people/a/" class="foto"></a></p>
  <p><a href="http://www.monkie.com.br" onclick="return false"><img src="https://lorempixel.com/100/100/people/b" class="foto"></a></p>
  <p><a href="http://www.monkie.com.br" onclick="return false"><img src="https://lorempixel.com/100/100/people/c"></a></p>
  <p><a href="http://www.monkie.com.br" onclick="return false"><img src="https://lorempixel.com/100/100/people/d"></a></p>
  <p><a href="http://www.monkie.com.br" onclick="return false"><img src="https://lorempixel.com/100/100/people/e" class="foto"></a></p>
</div>

<div id="B" nowrap></div>

<input type="hidden" id="nome" value="foto"/>
```

O **detalhe** fica por conta de replicar somente as `className` cujo o valor(foto) esta definido neste `input type='hidden' id='nome'` posto no exemplo.

A `div id="A"` esta na vertical, simboliza uma *playlist* no projeto real, e ja `div id="B"`, esta na horizontal alinhado a esquerda onde simboliza elementos relacionados quando escolhido pelo clique na playlist. Ambas tem papel distintos, regras CSS diferentes.

Por isso da questão. Não posso reutilizar o CSS da `div id="A"` por `div id="B"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Segue como resposta o *snippet* da Pergunta agora corrigido e em perfeito funcionamento. Veja:

```js
var resultado = document.getElementById('B');

var str = document.getElementById('nome').value;

if (document.getElementsByClassName(str)) {
    
var figura = document.getElementsByTagName('img');

var evento = document.body.getElementsByTagName('a');

    for (var i in figura, evento) {

        var image = figura[i];
        var titulo = image.className;
        var endereco =  image.src;

        var clic = evento[i];
        var link = clic.href;

        if (titulo == str) {
         var xerox = image;
         var copia = endereco;

         var clique = link;
         resultado.innerHTML += '<p><a href="'+ clique +'"><img src="' + copia + '" class="' + xerox + '"></a></p>'
            }   
        }
}
```

```css
#A {
        float : right;
        width : 115px;
        height : 400px;
        overflow: auto;
        padding  : 10px;
        border : thin solid silver;
}

#B { 
        overflow-x: auto;
        overflow-y: hidden;
        width : 400px;
        height : 100px;
        padding  : 10px;
        border : thin solid silver;
} 

#B p {
       padding : 10px;
       margin : 0 auto;
       cursor : pointer;
       display : inline-blinkk;
       display : inline;
       vertical-align : top;
}
```

```html
<div id="A">
       <p><a href="javascript:void(0)"><img src="https://lorempixel.com/100/100/people/a/" class="foto"></a></p>
       <p><a href="javascript:void(0)"><img src="https://lorempixel.com/100/100/people/b" class="foto"></a></p>
       <p><a href="javascript:void(0)"><img src="https://lorempixel.com/100/100/people/c"></a></p>
       <p><a href="javascript:void(0)"><img src="https://lorempixel.com/100/100/people/d"></a></p>
       <p><a href="javascript:void(0)"><img src="https://lorempixel.com/100/100/people/e" class="foto"></a></p>
</div>

<div id="B" nowrap></div>

<input type="hidden" id="nome" value="foto"/>
```